# QueryMalformedException

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I am configuring a custom search for a Sharepoint application, and I am having trouble forming the FullTextSqlQuery query.

My code earns a QueryMalformedException (Your query is malformed. Please rephrase your query.) when I attempt to execute the query.

Here is my code:

search = new FullTextSqlQuery(site);
search.QueryText = string.Format("select Title, Path, Description, Rank, Size FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'Documents' AND CONTAINS (\"{0}\")", EntreeScope.FormProperties["searchBox"]);

where the value of scope.FormProperties["searchBox"] is the query text and site is the current SPSite. Documents is a defined Search Scope on the default Search Service Application on the server.

Thanks in advance,

Brent

Comment: Try ' instead of " in the contains()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
search = new FullTextSqlQuery(site); search.QueryText = string.Format("select Title, Path, Description, Rank, Size FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'Documents' AND CONTAINS ('\"{0}\"')", EntreeScope.FormProperties["searchBox"]);
```

Really just adding single quotes around your contains criteria

Check out [CONTAINS Predicate in SharePoint Search SQL Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513993.aspx) for more details because it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your help. That worked like a charm. I overlooked the single quote in that mess of double quotations and symbols.